# How to get the count on likes and comments for a list of twitter handle

Tags: r, twitter, count, social-likes

I am working in R and trying to extract the number of total likes and comments for a list of twitter handles. I am completely clueless, any help will be appreciated. I have set up the API and installed the necessary libraries.

Any leads will be appreciated, thank you

```
install.packages("twitteR")
library(twitteR)
install.packages("rtweet")
library(rtweet)
install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)
install.packages("RCurl")
library(RCurl)
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
install.packages("RJSONIO")
library(RJSONIO)
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
install.packages("ROAuth")
library(ROAuth)
#Setting up twitter API

consumer_key <- "key"
consumer_secret <- "key"
access_token <- "key"
access_secret <- "key"
options(httr_oauth_cache=T) 
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,
                consumer_secret,
                access_token,
                access_secret)

#reading csv and extracting the followers and tweets count


users <- read.csv("Twitter.csv", skip = 1)
users1 <- lookupUsers(users[1:50,1])
```

Comment: Add some more details please. what API's and libraries are you trying to use, What have you started writing so far, etc. please make the request more concise to what you are trying to accomplish. Right now the ask is for someone to write it for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

In R, using [rtweet](https://rtweet.info/), below is the information you will get about a user

```
library(rtweet)

x <- rtweet::lookup_users("jdatap")
names(x)
 [1] "user_id"                 "status_id"               "created_at"             
 [4] "screen_name"             "text"                    "source"                 
 [7] "display_text_width"      "reply_to_status_id"      "reply_to_user_id"       
[10] "reply_to_screen_name"    "is_quote"                "is_retweet"             
[13] "favorite_count"          "retweet_count"           "hashtags"               
[16] "symbols"                 "urls_url"                "urls_t.co"              
[19] "urls_expanded_url"       "media_url"               "media_t.co"             
[22] "media_expanded_url"      "media_type"              "ext_media_url"          
[25] "ext_media_t.co"          "ext_media_expanded_url"  "ext_media_type"         
[28] "mentions_user_id"        "mentions_screen_name"    "lang"                   
[31] "quoted_status_id"        "quoted_text"             "quoted_created_at"      
[34] "quoted_source"           "quoted_favorite_count"   "quoted_retweet_count"   
[37] "quoted_user_id"          "quoted_screen_name"      "quoted_name"            
[40] "quoted_followers_count"  "quoted_friends_count"    "quoted_statuses_count"  
[43] "quoted_location"         "quoted_description"      "quoted_verified"        
[46] "retweet_status_id"       "retweet_text"            "retweet_created_at"     
[49] "retweet_source"          "retweet_favorite_count"  "retweet_retweet_count"  
[52] "retweet_user_id"         "retweet_screen_name"     "retweet_name"           
[55] "retweet_followers_count" "retweet_friends_count"   "retweet_statuses_count" 
[58] "retweet_location"        "retweet_description"     "retweet_verified"       
[61] "place_url"               "place_name"              "place_full_name"        
[64] "place_type"              "country"                 "country_code"           
[67] "geo_coords"              "coords_coords"           "bbox_coords"            
[70] "status_url"              "name"                    "location"               
[73] "description"             "url"                     "protected"              
[76] "followers_count"         "friends_count"           "listed_count"           
[79] "statuses_count"          "favourites_count"        "account_created_at"     
[82] "verified"                "profile_url"             "profile_expanded_url"   
[85] "account_lang"            "profile_banner_url"      "profile_background_url" 
[88] "profile_image_url"
```

**EDIT**

Based on your updated code. Below is a reproducible example.

```
users <- data.frame(
    name = c("jdatap", "dataandme"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

`rtweet::lookup_users` only works on objects of class `character`

```
users <- data.frame(
    name = c("jdatap", "dataandme")
)

class(users$name)
[1] "factor"

rtweet::lookup_users(users = users$name)
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Whereas, with a `character` vector all goes well.

```
users <- data.frame(
    name = c("jdatap", "dataandme"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

`rtweet::lookup_users` only works on objects of class `character`

```
users <- data.frame(
    name = c("jdatap", "dataandme"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

class(users$name)
[1] "character"

# works just not showing huge output here
users <- rtweet::lookup_users(users = users$name)
```

So when you read the csv with `read.csv` set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` like so.

```
users <- read.csv("Twitter.csv", skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note the above is based on the `rtweet` package, I strongly suggest you switch from using `twitteR`, as stated on the `twitteR` [github page](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR).

> This is the start of a relatively leisurely deprecation period for twitteR, in favor of using rtweet. Please start looking to switch over to that package. If you have any questions contact myself or @mkearney

Comment: Thank you! It gives me an error 'Error in readRDS(x) : error reading from connection'. Would you know whats the issue?

Comment: Where do you get this error, on `rtweet::lookup_users`? Check the rtweet [Obtaining and using access tokens
](https://rtweet.info/articles/auth.html) which explains how to get a token. Then use `rtweet::lookup_users("jdatap", token = your_token)` where `your_token` is the object returned by `create_token` (i.e.: `your_token <- create_token()`)

Comment: I successfully created a token but when I try to use one of the labels like retweet_location, it says function not available

Comment: Yes, this helps. Thank you

Comment: when I use your edit, it says Error: 'lookup_user' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rtweet'. Do you know why this is so? I have installed rtweet and all other necessary packages

Comment: I've edited it, it's `lookup_users` not `lookup_user` (plural not singular). Apologies.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. When I try to look up a user it is not storing anything in x. (in your above example, x has some data stored after looking up "jdatap' right? In my case it says x has 0 observations and 0 variables) Not sure whats the problem here

Comment: Do other calls from `rtweet` return data? Are you sure you have correctly  created the token and that it is loaded in your environment? Are you sure you are looking for a user that exists?

Comment: I have edited my code to show exactly what I have done. I have set it up correctly and installed the necessary libraries as well.